# I can't set webdriver.wait correctly

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I try to get access to audio captcha. So i use selenium webdriver. But i don't understand how to set webdriver wait correctly. When i start my code it seems that webdriver don't wait any second.
What do i set wrong?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

##proxy = "113.160.218.14:54432" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

proxies = ['94.79.52.207:8080', '5.45.64.97:3128', '46.105.190.36:3128',
           '45.224.129.169:8080', '168.11.14.250:8009']
proxy = random.choice(proxies)

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
chromedriver = 'chromedriver'
os.environ['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = chromedriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get('https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox']/div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark']"))).click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-audio-button"]'))).click()
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: No, i`m not. 
The web driver simply does not wait for the specified time and immediately goes to another frame on the audio captcha

Comment: The WebdriverWait(driver,10)  is actually wait for 10 seconds to find out element. If not it will throw you exception but if it found element before 10 seconds it will go to next operation.

Comment: If you want to slow down your execution use time.sleep(10) it will wait for 10seconds before proceeding.

Comment: Update the question with the _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_ and exactly where you are stuck. Please elaborate why do you want _webdriver to wait any second_ if net elements are available for actions to be performed.